# I18n translation missing only for admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I try to translate my web app and follow this guide:  [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

I make my el.yml for my language (greek), my Gemfile have gem 'rails-i18n' and my code in application_controller have

```
 before_filter :set_locale

 def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
 end

def default_url_options(options={})
    logger.debug "default_url_options is passed options: #{options.inspect}\n"
{ :locale => I18n.locale }
end
```

In my application.html.erb I use

```
 <%= l(Time.now, :format => :short) %></p
```

and everything is Okay with my users looking the time in Greek. But the first 5 ids from Users is admins and admins_controller handle articles. When an admin look the time take this error:

```
I18n::MissingTranslationData in Admin#articles
Showing /home/panagiotis/projects/diplomatiki/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #43 raised:
translation missing: el?state=4.time.formats.short
```

-

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
```

all work with ApplicationController why dont with AdminController (inherit)?

Answer (score 0):

Final solution for my problem deletes the follow code

```
before_filter :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end

def default_url_options(options={})
  logger.debug "default_url_options is passed options: #{options.inspect}\n"
   { :locale => I18n.locale }
end
```

with this code all links have extension like el? and my default links didn't work
Now I have with l(Time.now, :format => :short) everything in Greek.